# Copying PHP files from one server to another

Tags: php, copy

I am trying to copy some files from one server to another using PHP.
Its working perfectly for text and image files, however, if the file I try to copy is a PHP file itself it bombs and copies some funny data as though it was trying to execute the file.
Is there a special way to copy example.php from server A to server B?

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($serverAFiles); $i++) 
{
  set_time_limit(1800);
  $serverAFiles[$i] = trim($serverAFiles[$i] );
  copy ($serverAFiles[$i] , $serverBFiles[$i]);
}
```

Comment: How are you exactly copying your files? What method are you using? Post your code.

Comment: If you are using get_file_contents or cURL this won't work with php like you expect. What you see is correct. This is to avoid stealing information and files. I that was possible I could just copy the entire Facebook-code and make my own network. Or open the file and access their database.

Comment: 'for($i = 0; $i < count($serverAFiles); $i++)
 {
  set_time_limit(1800);
  $serverAFiles[$i]  = trim($serverAFiles[$i] );
  copy ($serverAFiles[$i] , $serverBFiles[$i]);
 }'

Comment: @OptimusCrime: But thats on the developer to  stop code injection. Of course, you can;t inject a code on a site like FB.

Comment: I don't want to hack FB. I have remote servers I want to update example.php on all of them without having to manually go to each one with a flash stick...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FTP or ssh with the correct credentials of course. For ssh you can use [shell_exec](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) and for FTP there is an [extension](http://no.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php). To copy the file that is executed, try to make a copy of the contents first and they sending it away.

Comment: Hmmm thanks for your help. I just have one question. These are my servers and they are running xampp. I don't have any passwords/usernames. I can access them by going to 192.168.x.x on my local network. What credentials would I use?

Comment: you are on windows network? you asked about copying files from a server to another. If there is another server that should have a method of auth.

Comment: Yes Windows. I'll look around.